# How to paint a closed area which consists of separate lines on сanvas js?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I use canvas and draw a closed area and want the area to fill by some color. Here is how I do it. I draw closed area with lines

1. I draw line (1)
2. Next line (2) starts from end of the previous one
3. Last line (3) starts from end of line (2) and ends at the start of line (1)

So as result I have closed area and want to fill by some color

Here is the chunk of code I used:

```
context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
context.fill();
```

But it not works. Неre is the code I use to accomplish the task.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="978" height="900"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      // begin custom shape
      context.beginPath();
      // line (1)
      context.moveTo(10, 10);
      context.lineTo(190, 190);
      // line (2)
      context.moveTo(190, 190);
      context.lineTo(200, 280);
      // line (3)
      context.moveTo(200, 280);
      context.lineTo(10, 10);
      // here I try fill the area by color
      context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
      context.fill();
      
      context.stroke();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="978" height="900"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      // begin custom shape
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(70, 70);
      context.lineTo(290, 290);
      context.lineTo(300, 380);
      context.closePath()
      context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
      context.fill();
      context.stroke();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```